# How to run my first nunit test

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to learn how to use Nunit tests. I have this simple code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter two numbers\n");
        int number1;
        int number2;
        number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        MathsHelper helper = new MathsHelper();
        int x = helper.Add(number1, number2);
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe sum of " + number1 +
            " and " + number2 + " is " + x);
        Console.ReadKey();
        int y = helper.Subtract(number1, number2);
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe difference between " +
              number1 + " and" + number2 + "  is " + y);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MathsHelper
{
    public MathsHelper() { }
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        int x = a + b;
        return x;
    }

    public int Subtract(int a, int b)
    {
        int x = a - b;
        return x;
    }
```

And i also created a unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [TestCase]
        public void AddTest()
        {
            MathsHelper helper = new MathsHelper();
            int result = helper.Add(20, 10);
            Assert.AreEqual(30, result);
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void SubtractTest()
        {
            MathsHelper helper = new MathsHelper();
            int result = helper.Subtract(20, 10);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, result);
        }
    }
}
```

I downloaded from Nuget Nunit.runner , Nunit.concole and Nunit.adapter. But if I run all tests it says that I am not having any tests in my projects. Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Default Proccessor Architecture under Test > Test Settings > Default Proccessor Architecture and rebuild solution.

Comment: Did you downloaded all elements of the same version? If you donwladed Nunit of 2.x and runner of 3.0, then it won't work.

Comment: I am using everyting in 3.0.1 version

Answer (score 0):

You are using `[TestCase]` attribute to mark the method as a test. This is suitable for parameterized tests. Your tests are not parameterized, that's why it doesn't work.

`[Test]` attribute should be used in your case. Please refer [`TestAttribute` doc](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Test-Attribute):

> The Test attribute is one way of marking a method inside a TestFixture class as a test. It is normally used for simple (non-parameterized) tests ...

Try the following:

```
    ...

    [Test]
    public void AddTest()
    {
        MathsHelper helper = new MathsHelper();
        int result = helper.Add(20, 10);
        Assert.AreEqual(30, result);
    }

    ...
```

That should work.